# How can I tell if whether my PowerShell module function was called by C# application or from the command line?

Tags: powershell

How can I tell if whether my PowerShell module function was called by my .NET / C# application (production) or from the command line (unit testing)?  I'm running PowerShell v5, .NET 4.5.x .

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Host.Name` shows me the name of the host application and allows me to distinguish between prod and test.